# tabControl, is there a way to add new tabs while im in my application?

Tags: c#, .net, tabcontrol

Im relativley new to tabControl and I was wonding if there is a way to add new tabs from inside my application? (from when it is started that is)

What I'm thinking is that I could probably do something like this..

Create a button and add a function to it like so..

```
private void addTabButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   tabControl1.addtab <- or something like that, I dont know the correct function. Not even sure if there is any
}
```

I would need help finding what the correct function name for adding a new tab.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb7xae05(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
private void addTabButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Tabpage tp = new TabPage();
   tp.Name = "tp" + this.tabControl1.TabCount;
   tp.Text = "tp" + this.tabControl1.TabCount;
   tp.Controls.Add(new Label()); //Or whatever you want added.
   this.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
}
```

So you dynamically make a tab and can set all the properties of the tabpage here as you wish. The naming and text setting that I use the TabCount for makes the tabpages at least a little more dynamic and different.